# Is there a way to indicate one or more in PLY's grammar?

Tags: python, grammar, ply

I would like to write a grammar rule of the nature:

```
program = { expression }
```

where `{}` indicates 1 or more.

For example, Lua's grammar uses the same syntax:

```
chunk ::= {stat [`;´]} [laststat [`;´]]
```

Is this possible? Does this conform with context free grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best simple solution is:

```
program : expression
        | program NEWLINE expression
```

This only works since PLY generates LR grammars, a nonterminal can't begin with itself (left-recursion) in LL grammars (if you were using a tool such as ANTLR)

You could also do:

```
program : expression
        | expression NEWLINE program
```

This second version is nice because it's compatible with both LL and LR grammars, but I believe the first rule is more efficient for an LR parser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
program : expression
        | expression NEWLINE expression
```